# Looking up .class-files via Classloader.getResource() on Android

Tags: android, classloader, dexclassloader

I am trying to build an Android application which uses the XMLBeans library.

The library tries to look up .class-files via

```
ClassLoader cl = SchemaDocument.class.getClassLoader();
URL resource = cl.getResource("xyz.class");
```

It seems this does not work on Android, probably due to the dexclassloader and different packaging of code and resources in the .apk-files via "dex-files".

I agreed that this code is strange and should rather use `Class.forName()` properly,
which seems to work. I will work with the library-devs to see if it can be changed.

But it would still be good to make this work somehow, so is there a way to make
`getResource("xyz.class")` work on Android as well?

Comment: The package path?

Comment: I tried that, i.e. `getResource("a/b/c/xyz.class")`, the same code on JVM works fine.